# Ubuntu repositories question

Tags: software-installation, repository

I want to know are they repositories for Ubuntu like for Arch. I mean that for arch all programs you can download it(latest version) from software repositories. But for Ubuntu some aps like Eclipse, i need to download it from official site and when i download it i don't get updates from apt-get. (In official repositories is old version).

Comment: Arch is known to support newest apps releases while Ubuntu is a bit more conservative.

Comment: Ok but some aps are not in Ubuntu repositories, like atom or VS Code

Comment: @PetkoKamenov …which are quite new pieces of SW.

Answer (score 1):

**In Ubuntu**, there is the Ubuntu repository which you can find most of popular apps and you only need to write:

```
sudo apt-get install app
```

However some apps needs to be downloaded and manually updated such as Eclipse(If you wish there is an old version of eclipse in Ubuntu Store)

There are two ways of download these apps. Either you find a PPA(Personal Package Archives) that includes this app and its update, or you can download the tar file, extract it to install and manually update from apps menu(such as Eclipse)

You can find PPA's related to your apps(f.e Oracle Java JDK by Webupd8). Searching with "app PPA" will find you related PPA's often.

Comment: No there are not here the most popular aps. I am not Ubuntu (Linux ) begginer and i know all that.(I use Ubuntu and Linux for about 4 years) But for example Atom is not in Ubuntu repositories, but it is on Manjaro one.